# Prestashop updating from 1.7.4.4 to 1.7.5.0 results in HTTP 500 error in FO and BO

Tags: mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

PrestaShop version: 1.7.4.4 (I updated all the way up from 1.7.3.4)
PHP version: 7.1
1-Click update version: 4.5.1

Once I update to 1.7.5.0 via the 1 click update, the update goes through. The only warnings I receive are as follows:

```
[WARNING] SQL 1.7.5.0 1060 in ALTER TABLE `ps_supply_order_receipt_history` CHANGE `employee_firstname` `employee_firstname` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '', CHANGE `employee_lastname` `employee_firstname` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '': Duplicate column name 'employee_firstname'

[WARNING] SQL 1.7.5.0 1060 in ALTER TABLE `ps_product` CHANGE `reference` `supplier_reference` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE `supplier_reference` `supplier_reference` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL: Duplicate column name 'supplier_reference'

[WARNING] SQL 1.7.5.0 1060 in ALTER TABLE `ps_stock_available` ADD `location` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' AFTER `out_of_stock`: Duplicate column name 'location'
```

I've turned on debug mode, but I only receive a error 500 message:

This page isn’t working domain.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

On FO and BO.

I've tried the RC1, beta and stable branch.

Comment: pls show us what's in the server logs. 500 errors should leave a trace in the server logs

Answer (score 0):

did you delete the /var/cache/prod/class_index.php and the /var/cache/dev/class_index.php?